# BlockUI jquery plugin keeps page blocked after "back" button. Opera/FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I use jquery [blockUI plugin (v2)](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#overview) and call `$.blockUI` when user submits a form. Web page smoothly fades out and new page appears. That's ok. But when user presses "back" button in opera/fire fox he observes fade out page with hourglass mouse cursor that is completely blocked.

Chrome/IE visualize page ok.

What would you suggest?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I found workaround.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
                $.unblockUI();                
})
```